# Config transforms stop working in TFS 2010 when VS2010 project is migrated to VS2012 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, transform, config

I may not be asking the right question but here's what is happening.

1. We create a VS 2010 project (called "Test.csproj") and add transforms for Test and Stage environments.
2. We create build definitions in VS 2010 and used the following MSBuild arguments:

   /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
3. TFS 2010 builds and transforms the web.config as expected.
4. A VS 2012 user opens the Test.csproj and migrates the project to VS 2012, checks it in to TFS 2010.
5. TFS 2010 builds but does not transform the web.config as expected.

What hasn't worked:
Manually adding a "TransformXml" task to a project's AfterBuild event, I get a "Task not found" error.

Using:
Server 2008 R2 - TFS 2010 - Web Deploy 3.5
Clients are Win 7 - VS 2010 SP1 / VS 2012

Web Deployment does not seem to be working either.  The person who set this up is no longer with us so I'm learning as I go.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install VS2012 on your build server.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking back, that does appear to be the solution.  We took a slightly different route with replacing the C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild folder on our TFS 2010 with the folder from a development machine that had VS2010 SP1 and VS2012 installed.